# How to store session variable in database

Tags: php, database, variables, session

I am actually new to PHP. My problem is that the session does not store in my database.

here's is my demo_session1.php

```
<?php
$Refno="";
// Start the session
session_start();

$_SESSION["$Refno"] = "HNo1";
echo "Ref no.:HNO1";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $Refno  = $_POST['Refno'];

}
?>

<html>
<body>
<a href="demo_session2.php">Arrange to view property</a>

</body>
</html>
```

here's my demo_session2.php:

```
<?php
$Refno = $message= ""; 
$messageErr = "";

session_start();
require "configdemo.php";
echo "Ref no.: " . $_SESSION["$Refno"] . ".<br>";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$Refno  = $_POST['Refno'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
}

 if (empty($_POST["message"])) 
{
     $messageErr = "Please leave a message for the agent.";
   }

else
{

 $sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO demo (Refno, message) VALUES 

('$Refno' , '$message') ") or die("Can't Insert! ");
          header ("location: thanks.php"); 
         }

?>
<style>
.error {
color: #FF0000;
font-size:12px;
text-transform: lowercase;
}
</style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" >
<form name="viewing_form" method="post" action="">
<tr>
<td>Message: <td><textarea name="message"rows="5" cols="25" value="<?php echo 

$message;?>"></textarea>
<td><span class="error"> <?php echo $messageErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel"></td>
</body>
</html>
```

The "Refno" displays on the demo_session2.php, but when I press the submit button only the message is inserted into the database. I want also the "Refno" to be inserted.

Comment: Should: _$_SESSION["$Refno"]_  really be _$_SESSION[**"Refno"**]_? Note: remove the _$_ from 'Refno' when used an an array index. Currently it uses the value of $Refno as the index.

Comment: Off-topic: be aware that you're writing SQL-injectable code. You have no control over the value of `$message` yet you concatenate it onto one SQL statement that you then blindly execute.

Comment: I removed the dollar sign but to no avail. I want the 'Refno' to be inserted into the database. The 'Refno' is actually a session variable, it has been displayed from demo_session1.php to demo_session2.php.

Sorry if i am being pain but I am not understanding the logic behind.

Comment: Immediately before this: _if(isset($_POST['submit']))_ please do: _var_dump($Refno, $_POST['Refno'], $_SESSION["$Refno"]);_. It should give you some clues as to what is happening. Please edit your answer with the results if it is still not clear.

Comment: I am getting the following Notices: 

Notice: Undefined index: Refno in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo_session2.php on line 8
Ref no.: .

Notice: Undefined index: Refno in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo_session2.php on line 10
string(0) "" NULL string(4) "HN01"

Comment: What do you get when you submit the form? The notice messages are harmless for now. You want the values when the form is submitted. You can then work out what will happen in the query given the data that is supplied.

Answer (score 2):

- Remove the $ Sign from $_SESSION Refno (as Vincent mentioned)
- If I see this correctly, your form does not contain a field with the name "Refno". So there will be no $_POST['Refno']. So either you add such a field or you use the SESSION in the QUERY:

  > $sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO demo (Refno, message) VALUES
  >   ('$_SESSION[Refno]' , '$message') ") or die("Can't Insert! ");

And as Karel mentioned, it would be appropriate to escape the $message with [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Hello Marc :) Well, thank you. It worked perfectly.

Now, I have another problem. I want the first name and last name of the user to be displayed as well. I have been adding this ('$_SESSION[fname]' but it does not work. I mean the user is already registered and the data are in the database. how do I retrieve them?

Comment: hello @Marc, it is still unresolved

i retrieved data from my table new member, they display clearly. but now i want to input them into another table. unfortunately, it cannot insert. I know i am not doing it the right way, just hoping that you can tell me where the error lies. Thanks :)

Comment: demo2.php

`session_start();
echo "Ref no.: " . $_SESSION["propertyno"] . ".<br>";
echo "Ref no.: " . $_SESSION["username"] . ".<br>";
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);

$sql = "SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, email FROM newmember WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows>0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "First Name: " . $row["First_Name"] . " <br>";
        echo   "Last Name: " . $row["Last_Name"] . "<br>";
        echo   "Email Address: " . $row["email"] . "<br>";
   }
}`

Comment: So what you want to do is inserting data into another db table? You can do this with a SQL insert query: $conn->query("INSERT INTO mytable ('First_Name','Last_Name','email')
VALUES ('John', 'Doe, 'fancy@example.com')");

Comment: Hi @Marc. It's still not working. I don't have to input the records manually but on submit form, they should enter in my table. I retrieved the data successfully, but i am getting **Notice: Undefined index** for the attributes.

Comment: Do you need further help on this? Otherwise would accepting the answer help to keep stackoverflow cleaned up